# Joda time - Parsing when the format varies

Tags: java, parsing, jodatime

I am receiving date/time strings from a website that seem to have a variable number of digits for the milliseconds value.

Sample:

> 2013-08-15T06:21:49.35054+01:00
>
> 2013-08-15T06:21:49.350546+01:00
>
> 2013-08-15T06:21:49+01:00

Currently I use:

```
static final Map<Integer,DateTimeFormatter> parsers = new HashMap<Integer,DateTimeFormatter>();
static {
  parsers.put("2013-07-23T22:44:00+01:00".length(),
              DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"));
  parsers.put("2013-07-27T18:00:59.9+01:00".length(),
              DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SZ"));
  parsers.put("2013-07-27T18:00:59.99+01:00".length(),
              DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSZ"));
  parsers.put("2013-07-27T18:00:59.999+01:00".length(),
              DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"));
  parsers.put("2013-07-27T18:00:59.9999+01:00".length(),
              DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSZ"));
  parsers.put("2013-07-27T18:00:59.99999+01:00".length(),
              DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSZ"));
  parsers.put("2013-07-27T18:00:59.999999+01:00".length(),
              DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ"));
  parsers.put("2013-07-27T18:00:59.9999999+01:00".length(),
              DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZ"));
}

public static Date parseDate(String date) {
  return parsers.get(date.length()).parseDateTime(date).toDate();
}
```

Is there a tidier way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution to my specific problem of the variable number of digits in the ms field.

```
static final DateTimeFormatter isoParser = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser();

public static Date parseDate(String date) {
  return isoParser.parseDateTime(date).toDate();
}
```

However - I would be interested in a more general solution that can handle any of several possible but distinguishable formats.

Answer (score 0):

Why not split on the `+` symbol, and append the required remaining decimal places ? eg. change

```
2013-08-15T06:21:49.35054
```

to

```
2013-08-15T06:21:49.350540
```

and then just use the *one* `DateTimeFormat`

Comment: Could do - yes. But then there's the fiddly bit of dealing with the case where there is no milliseconds value. Not ideal but certainly one option. IMHO That's really just moving the issue elsewhere though.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use this way since you are dealing with ISO-8601

```
public static Date getDateFromIsoISO8601(String str) {
        try {
            return ISO8601Utils.parse(str, new ParsePosition(0));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Parsing","error:getDateFromIsoISO8601: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Use Joda-time